# getting property inside sub class using java inheritance?

Tags: java

I have below classes.

```
public abstract class BaseRequest{

    protected SomeEntity entity;

    public BaseRequest() {
        entity= new SomeEntity();
    }
        public void setName(String name){
           entity.setName(name);
        }
        public void setAge(String age){
           entity.setAge(age);
        }
}
```

---

```
public class Request extends BaseRequest{

    private String address;

    public Request() {
        super();
    }
        public void setAddress(String address){
           this.address=address;
        }
        public String getAddress(){
          return this.address;
        }
}
```

I create **BaseRequest** because it can be used by many sub classes. Also clients should not have access to **SomeEntity** property of **BaseRequest.java**
Now clients can use `Request` as below.

```
Request re = new Request();
re.setName("xxx");
re.setAge("xxxxx");
re.setAddress("xxxxxx");
```

and clients will send this request to service method as below.

```
public void saveData(Request request){

  //here i should get SomeEntity instance directly.

}
```

To get SomeEntity populated instance directly i can provide a getter method in `BaseRequest.java`. But if i provide a getter then even clients can also get SoemEntity instance by instantiating **Request** class. which i dont want to allow the clients to access it. Now the question is is there any best way to get someEntity instace inside saveData() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you need a protected getter for someEntity in `BaseRequest`

```
protected SomeEntity  getSomeEntity() {
    return someEntity; 
}
```

With this getter you don't need a protected `entity` field in `BaseRequest`, thus you can make it private.